# Setup a Facebook Messenger Robot for another user?

Tags: facebook, messenger, facebook-chatbot

I am developing a generic Messenger Robot that walks the user through a structured conversation. The user of the Robot can share whatever they like through configuration.  For example someone could setup their life story and go through it in stages, childhood, college, professional life.  Each of those stage could be broken down into sub-stages and so on.

Is there a way I can setup the bot for FB users?  I don't want to have to go on the user FB profile in order to create a bot for them.  I'd like my website or FB app to be able to set it up for the user without an fuss on their part.  The user would just give the story and allow FB access while all the technical details would be handled in the background.

Ideas are appreciated,

--Matt

Comment: Without visiting facebook completely it's not possible. You can check https://www.gupshup.io/developer/home . They have implemented chatbot   service. But for some steps fb visit is must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap this up, a 3rd party can access a users Pages via the Facebook Login feature. Once logged in the 3rd party can generate an Access Token for the page.  With the Access Token, the 3rd party can receive and send messages with a Bot.